# Tree instance geometry nodes don't follow the weight painting

Tags: geometry-nodes, weight-painting, properties

I'm follwing this [Youtube tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3INTJfdmjbs), my trees just spawn randomly without following the weight painting on the landscape plane.

[Blend file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ja2M422XvObT5WS694fwswkSoS90cH4P/view?usp=sharing)

[image]

Comment: pls provide blend file, thx

Comment: Posted a google drive file

Comment: You haven't actually added the nodes that you need to control the position and density in the Blend file that you posted. If you continue the tutorial from around [here](https://youtu.be/3INTJfdmjbs?t=423) you'll find that everyything works correctly.

Comment: Damn i didn't think about watching all of it first

Comment: You only needed to watch another minute of it and you wouldn't have needed to wake us up! :^)

Answer (score 1):

connect selection to your input node

[image]

choose "Group" in your GN modifier

result see above